# Unable to Run Tests with Cucumber, Selenium, Java 18 and Junit

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

I have already seen some similar issues into other questions but I still be unable to solve my problem. It is weird that I was able to run these tests but not any more and I don't know why.

**Info about my project:**

This is a basic project with Java and Seleniun.

**Java JDK version**: 18.0.2.1

**Gradle version**: 7.5

**Cucumber**

**Junit verssion**:  4.13.2

**OS**: Windows 11

**Implemented with Page Object Model**:

[image]

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
   }
group 'GerUdemy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 13

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.13.2'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.6.0'

    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.11.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.11.1'
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '7.11.1'

    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '2.0.3'

    implementation group: 'tech.grasshopper', name: 'extentreports-cucumber7-adapter', version: '1.9.1'

}

test{
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
```

These are the failings that get when run the tests. **Sorry but this is huge and I have cut some parts**

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test

@google
Scenario: As a user I enter a search criteria in Goggle # src/test/resources/features/Google.feature:4
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 34369
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1678994810.214][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 111.
[1678994810.219][WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
Mar 16, 2023 4:26:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

  Given I am on the Google search page                  # steps.GoogleSteps.navigateToGoogleSearchPage()
      io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class steps.GoogleSteps
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    ...
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$FinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:248)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at steps.GoogleSteps.<init>(GoogleSteps.java:9)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:56500/devtools/browser/9a9c85fc-4876-4308-bbdd-bf3e859a839c
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:77)
    ... 66 more    


Failed to instantiate class steps.GoogleSteps
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class steps.GoogleSteps
    at app//io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at app//io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at app//io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at app//io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at app//io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    rs.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base@18.0.2.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base@18.0.2.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at steps.GoogleSteps.<init>(GoogleSteps.java:9)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:56500/devtools/browser/9a9c85fc-4876-4308-bbdd-bf3e859a839c
Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
    at app//pages.BasePage.<clinit>(BasePage.java:27)
    ... 66 more

Could not initialize class pages.BasePage
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class pages.BasePage
    at runner.runner.cleanBrowser(runner.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:56500/devtools/browser/9a9c85fc-4876-4308-bbdd-bf3e859a839c [in thread "Test worker"]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:70)
    at pages.BasePage.<clinit>(BasePage.java:27)
    at steps.GoogleSteps.<init>(GoogleSteps.java:9)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    ...
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$StartTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:233)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$FinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:248)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    ... 23 more

????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
runner.runner > Test Google search functionality.As a user I enter a search criteria in Goggle FAILED
    io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException at DefaultObjectFactory.java:67
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79
            Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at GoogleSteps.java:9
                Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException at NettyWebSocket.java:102
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Unsafe.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at NettyWebSocket.java:102
runner.runner > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at runner.java:24
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at NettyWebSocket.java:102
2 tests completed, 2 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/AUTOMATION/practicas/java-selenium/practica-ger/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 6s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

**More info about this project:**

Google.feature:

```
Feature: Test Google search functionality

  @google
    Scenario: As a user I enter a search criteria in Goggle
      Given I am on the Google search page
      When I enter a search criteria
      And click on the search button
      Then results match the criteria
```

GooglePage.java

```
package pages;

public class GooglePage extends BasePage {

    //private String searchButton = "(//div/center/input[@name='btnK'])[2]";
    private String searchButton = "//body/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/center[1]/input[1]";
    private String searchTextField = "//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf gsfi')]";
    private String firstResult = "//h3[contains(text(),'Argentina.gob.ar: Inicio')]";

    public GooglePage() {

        super(driver);
    }

    public void navigateToGoogle() {

        navigateTo("https://www.google.com/");
    }

    public void clickGoogleSearch() {
        super.clickElement(searchButton);
    }

    public void enterSearchCriteria(String criteria){
        write(searchTextField, "Argentina");
    }

    public String firstResult(){
        return textFromElement(firstResult);
    }
}
```

GoogleSteps.java

```
package steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.junit.Assert;
import pages.GooglePage;

public class GoogleSteps {

    GooglePage google = new GooglePage();

    @Given("^I am on the Google search page$")
    public void navigateToGoogleSearchPage(){
        google.navigateToGoogle();
    }

    @When("^I enter a search criteria$")
    public void enterSearchCriteria(){
        google.enterSearchCriteria("Google");
    }

    @And("^click on the search button$")
    public void clickOnSearchButton(){
        google.clickGoogleSearch();
    }

    @Then("^results match the criteria$")
    public void validateResults(){
        Assert.assertEquals("Argentina.gob.ar: Inicio", google.firstResult());
    }
}
```

runner.java

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import pages.BasePage;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = "@google",
        plugin = { "pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumberreport.html",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        monochrome = true,
        glue = "steps"
)

public class runner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanBrowser(){
        BasePage.closeBrowser();
    }
}
```

BasePage.java

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;

public class BasePage {
    // static hace que haya un solo valor para todas las instancias de esta clase.
    // Es decir, una sola instancia de WebDriver compartida para todas las clases
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;
    private static Actions action;

    // bloque estatico que se va a ejecutar al comienzo
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\AUTOMATION\\practicas\\java-selenium\\practica-ger\\src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    //Constructor
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        BasePage.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        // [[[*]]] esto es el wait IMPLISCITO PURO que no es recomendable usar ya que va a esperar esos 10 segundos para cada accion.
        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void navigateTo(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public static void closeBrowser(){
        driv
```